# How to lengthen VMware Fusion suspend feature

Tags: vmware

VMware Fusion suspends VMs very aggressively (Windows 10 in my case) in under 30 minutes.

I have found how to stop it suspending at all - but how can you lengthen that time to, say, 1 or 2 hours - and a different amount on battery?

Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't Fusion only suspend guests when the guest OS wants to go into sleep or standby mode? In which case, the answer is to adjust the power management settings in the guest itself: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=92471339  Edit: looks like you can also turn off suspend on a per-machine basis:  https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2056501

Comment: Yes you got it - its based on the VM OS sleep settings. However - under "Power & Sleep" - there are only 2 otions "When plugged in, turn off the display after" and "When plugged in, PC goes to sleep after".

Do you know why there aren't 2 options for "When on battery"?

Comment: I figured it out - there is a 'pass through power status' option in advanced settings on the vm. Feel free to make this an answer if you want me to accept it - cheers.

Comment: Since you figured it out, feel free to answer it yourself and mark as accepted!